# Executed a javascript/jquery function for some time, then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 javascript function - f1, f2.
Ii want to call f2 from f1 in every 2 seconds and i need to do this for 10 minutes.

```
function f1()
{
   //call f1 in every 2 seconds- for 10 minutes
}

function f2(){
{

}
```

How can i implement this in javascript/jquery or how to use Settimeout, setInterval for the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cominbation of `setTimeout()`, and `setInterval()` like

kill after 10 minutes; 10*60*1000 = 600000 milliseconds

```
var loop2s = setInterval(function(){
           f2();
    }, 2000);
// Kill after 10  minutes
setTimeout(function(){

   clearInterval(loop2s);

},600000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call f2 from the function itself with a counter. 
Quick example:

```
var counter = 0;    
function f1()
{
    setTimeout(f2, 2000);
}

function f2(){
{
    counter++;
    if (counter < 59) {
        setTimeout(f2, 2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit overdone, but was an interesting problem to solve and became a nicer api by returning the stop function instead of using `window.clearInterval(someVar);`

```js
function f1(){
  // as a test this runs f2 every 400ms for 4 seconds
  var stop = interval( f2, 400, 4000 );
  // stop() is a function you can call to stop the timer asynchronously
}

function f2( elapsed ){
  console.log('called f2 at ' + elapsed + 'ms' );
}

f1();

/**
 * interval
 *
 * repeat the callback function every n milliseconds, until
 * timout or the stop() function is called
 *
 * @param {Function} cb       callback function to perform
 * @param {Number}   every    ms between interval
 * @param {Number}   timeout  timeout for interval
 *
 * @return {Function}  stop   stop function to clear the interval
 */
function interval( cb, every, timeout ){
  
  var start = Date.now(),
      timer = null;
  
  timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    var elapsed = Date.now() - start;
    if( timeout && elapsed > timeout ){
      stop();
    } else {
      cb( elapsed );
    }
  }, every);
  
  function stop(){
    window.clearInterval( timer );
  }
  
  return stop;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```